# Running OPL for several Hours with no result

Tags: cplex, opl, ilog

I have a relatively large problem in OPL. It has been running for over 24 hrs now but no response. Normally this type of problems runs for like 50 hrs or so but I can see progress of the number of solutions found and the gap. But in this particular problem I only have the following. Any suggestions on what could possibly have gone wrong.

My OPL code is fairly large at 630 lines, and has a dat file of 90 lines, the data is read from excel and written back to excel. If anyone is interested to  look into detail to help I can share the files

```
CPXPARAM_MIP_Tolerances_AbsMIPGap                0.10000000000000001
CPXPARAM_MIP_Tolerances_MIPGap                   0.10000000000000001
Presolve has eliminated 1511670 rows and 873012 columns...
Presolve has improved bounds 1707844 times...
Tried aggregator 1 time.
MIP Presolve eliminated 1511740 rows and 873092 columns.
MIP Presolve modified 140 coefficients.
Reduced MIP has 7484 rows, 633080 columns, and 22209973 nonzeros.
Reduced MIP has 3584 binaries, 0 generals, 0 SOSs, and 0 indicators.
Presolve time = 20.25 sec. (26633.79 ticks)
Tried aggregator 1 time.
```

Comment: It would indeed be helpful if you could share the model for this issue. It is best to set the "export format" in the settings file to SAV and then zip the generated SAV file before sharing. SAV is both, the most compact and most accurate representation of a model.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thank yo for your help. I have created a SAV file, but to share it I will need an email id, I dont see an option to attach here.  Can you please provide your email id at d.ranajit@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the MIP display parameter to 4 to get more information in the log. This should usually tell you where the solver is "stuck" and this may give an idea how to remedy.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, I have my ops file as below  but still I do not see any further lines in the engine log other than what I had goven above. I have been running the code for 3 hrs now. Is the below OK ?:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<settings version="2">
  <category name="run">
    <setting name="run_engineexportextension" value="sav"/>
  </category>
  <category name="cplex">
    <setting name="epagap" value="0.1"/>
    <setting name="epgap" value="0.1"/>
    <setting name="mipdisplay" value="4"/>
  </category>
</settings>

Comment: That looks odd. Maybe set the aggregator passes to 1 or disable symmetry detection. Maybe this gets you further.